# design a usercontrol for different scenario

Tags: c#

Now I am working on a registration system, there are basically three different scenario to get users' personal information (name, address e.g.)
1. prepopulate data from table1
2. prepopulate data from table2
3. empty for new user

I am trying to make a personal information usercontrol for these three situation, in this case  I guess I need a switch to determine which table to go. My question is does it worth to do this? Because I am not sure if the client will add more scenario in the future. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in general it's a good idea to follow the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle. If you're going to present the same user interface in two (or more) places you should attempt to code/design once and reuse it.

Even if you were presented with only one data source though you should attempt to decouple the presentation from the model and business logic.

It makes code maintenance and testing easier.

Comment: the pain is that the client always wants to do a tiny change for one situation (like add a text information) which makes me crazy

Answer (score 0):

Idea: Try to make as basic a Control as possible - one with as much common logic as possible, so it can work as a base for all three situations.

Now create three new controls that inherit from that base Control, while trying to keep the logic in those three as limited as possible.

Now hope that "the client" (?) will not add a very different scenario later; as long as any new scenario is not too different, you might anyway be able to make use of logic from the base controler again.

Hopefully, this will let you stick to the DRY principle, as Miky Dinescu mentions, while still enabling for existing and potential future variations.